# twitter bootstrap's button in navbar not correctly vertically aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment, navbar

I am having trouble positioning a `<button class='btn' />`element in the navbar when using `.pull-left`. See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6e49G/

The buttons are vertically offset which does not look that good:
[image]

Comment: btw. I'm using the today-released bootstrap 2.1.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this like I did, this issue seems to be fixed in version 2.3.0 of Bootstrap.
I was running 2.2.2 previously and had this exact problem (input-prepend or input-append), but only with buttons, not icons.  As a last resort I thought I'd check for an update of Bootstrap and thankfully that did the trick.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is fixed with 2.3.0. I've modified the above jsFiddle without changing anything but the bootstrap version, and it looks nice now. See: http://jsfiddle.net/zLk2U/

Answer (score 3):

You could also take the buttons out of the input prepend div and then apply the form-inline class to form and it should give you what you're looking for. See http://jsfiddle.net/6e49G/25/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like bootstrap not designed to have appended buttons in navbar. I solved it with the custom style. Your top margin cames from `.navbar` styles.

```
.navbar-form .input-prepend .btn { margin-top: 0px; } ​
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/6e49G/15/

Comment: sorry, although I marked your answer as the right answer (and it is, since it fixes my isseu): clicking the buttons will trigger a form submit with your solution, which is not what I want so I marked Noobie1 answer as the right one - where the problem does not occur.